# Does using design patterns makes java code slow?

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns

Does using design patterns makes java code slow? If I use extra interfaces and syntax constructions (like class wrap) will I get well organized but slow code or that won't make my code significantly slower?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will *not* make your code *significantly* slower. As some function calls are wrapped in additional classes or methodes, some method-calls are a little bit slower, but a human will not notice this. It's about nano-seconds. Allways prefere the advantage of good readable and reusable code.

I a high performance application, you should consider to refactor your code to a higher performance *after* designing and implementing it based on patterns. But normaly this is not needed.

And as always: It depends on the used pattern and the usecase of your program.

Comment: Well, a human **might** notice a nanosecond multiplied by a billion, so the argument can only be stated in percentage, not nanoseconds.

Comment: For example, in high-performance APIs like Lucene great attention is given to exactly this kind of issues.

Comment: +1 .... http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Write_Code_for_Humans_not_Machines

Comment: @Simulant: AFAIK, most of the complications comes from using indirect calls, and that's something what gets mostly completely optimized away. I agree with all the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Following your line of thought, one should never use Java in the first place because it is full of abstraction layers that make it more convenient to write correct and maintainable code, but reduce its speed below the speed of assembler or C. If you worry about wrappers making your code significantly slower, you probably have a use case that would make C a better fit than Java.

On the other hand, you should **definitely** take care not to overengineer and throw truckloads of patterns on every problem you see in your code. Use patterns judiciously, where you can clearly see the benefit, not just where you see a pattern might theoretically fit.

The way I prefer to code is to first make the simplest, dumbest solution that solves my immediate problem. If later I must add one or two more similar functions, giving rise to code duplication or other code smells, only then will I think about introducing an appropriate pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces make your code clearer and easier to change in future, but have no effect on speed, because they exist only to tell the compiler how your code fits together.

Design patterns patterns are commonly occuring solutions to common problems. If you have the problem then use one of the well-known solutions. Will it make your program slower? It depends on the choices *you* make between the available solutions. You need to understand the trade-offs of each pattern in order to nake the choice.

But without using a design pattern solution, you are using your own home grown DIY solution; when we do this we usually doesn't solve the problem as well, or as quickly (in our time, and in machine time), or as understandably for future maintenance. This last point is because design patterns give us a new way of talking about problems and solutions. Once we understand that new vocabulary, we can solve more complex prolems more easily.

So do they make your program slower? No, they make it work. Faster.

Enjoy your patterns reading. They make more sense if you have an actual problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the overhead of using design patterns is insignificant, and to be sure, just take a look at the code source of some java projects where the performence is needed like android, and you will be surprised that all of them use heavily design patterns.

However some design choices coud impact the performence , like choosing to use List instead of hashmap where the map is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, when using a permitted programming constructs, you should not worry about performance. JVM is good at keeping code optimized.  Most performance issues generally arise by the code where we write code related to thread synchronization, and where we do I/O such as DB calls.  Having few extra interfaces and classes to make your design modular and neat will not hurt. You may have to be bit careful if you are writing your own frameworks that rely on using reflections and other advanced features, if you do it sub-optimally, you can risk adding  performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases additional code wrapping makes code a bit slower. But in some cases this is not true. If you iterate >1 billion iterations, additional wrapping can be significantly slower. Good practice is first to write good readable and reusable code. And only after that try to profile and optimize code there is worst performance. Often you need change compute algorithm, but some times you need write workaround code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. As usual, there are no easy answers when it comes to a trade-off.

You have established that using a certain pattern will make the code clearer, but that may come at the cost of a performance penalty. So what do you do? You use your best judgement. Often that may be to first try the pattern and then test whether that's fast enough, and then optimizing as needed. Sometimes you already know that it has to be as fast as possible, or conversely, that the code is not performance-critical.